# Latency between Azure Web App and a VM

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App and an Azure VM running in the same data center under the same VNet. The web app can properly connect to the VM using its internal IP (as well as using the DNS server I've configured).
The VM runs the web app's database (SQL Server) thus I'd like the network latency to be the lowest possible (this is why I've put both machine in a VNet).
My question is how should I measure the latency ?
From within the VM, using "psping -l 1k -n 1000 -h 20 *public_url*:80" is ok when using the public address, but I wanna check the latency using the web app's internal IP and this cannot be resolved.

Thanks,
Noam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can test the latency from the Web App to your VM easily from [DebugConsole](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) for the Web App.

The other way around (VM to Web App over internal IP) may not be possible because Web Apps don't have a documented way of acquiring their internal IP and hostname.

Comment: How can I get internal address to connect web app to database in vm?